# More than one instances of block for different pages in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-regions

Is there anyway we can define more than one block structure for the pages?

For example... I want to two different block/region setting and that should be page specific...

So I can create literally 2-3 different region settings or page structure

Is there any way I can do that?

P.S: Other than multiblock... I already tried it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using panels you can create custom panes(like blocks) with specific settings etc and put them everywhere you want and so many times as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Panels?
https://drupal.org/project/panels

Panels allows you to set various page regions and also allows those regions to be enabled/disabled based on sets of matching criteria.